# Infix function with when - is it possible?

Tags: kotlin

is it possible to use infix function with when statement. Something similar to this:

```
infix fun Int.isGreater(value: Int): Boolean = this > value
```

and then:

```
when (value) {
    isGreater 2 -> doSomething()
    isGreater 1 -> doSomethingElse()
    else -> doNothing()
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? Actually: no... this will not work, but that has nothing to do with the `infix`...

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work. I am just curious if there is any possibility to achieve this kind of structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually: no, this will not work. The reason can be seen when consulting the [`when` grammar](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#when), which doesn't have a construct that takes the value given to `when` and calls functions of the `whenCondition` on it. So it doesn't have to do with the `infix` itself (while it is true that it needs a receiver on the left).

What you could do is the following:

```
when {
  value isGreater 2 -> ...
  value.isGreater(1) -> ...
```

If you like, you can also read more about `when` in the [Kotlin reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call infix functions like you do. It always needs a receiver on the left side:

```
when {
    value isGreater 2 -> doSomething()
    value isGreater 1 -> doSomethingElse()
    else -> doNothing()
}
```

> Note that infix functions always require both the receiver and the parameter to be specified. When you're calling a method on the current receiver using the infix notation, you need to use this explicitly; unlike regular method calls, it cannot be omitted.